# Is my pop3 email security enough for a simple home user?

Tags: security

As a retired home user I only need access to email from my desktop PC.

So I have used Evolution as mail client interacting with Gmail's server for many years. Receiving email is with Password and sending email is set to Plain; because Evolution in Ubuntu 18.04 does not support the Google security setup OAuth2.

I have read Ubuntu Community Wiki for a couple of hours and checked similar Ask Ubuntu questions.

Is my email secure enough? As an end user age 80 I am not skilled with terminal commands.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Six guys from Ubuntu users list responded with good advice within a day.

I am reassured that my use of Evolution is safe.

So this question has been answered. Thanks. Chas